# What was written on the arrow which Wonder Woman receives from Amazons?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

In *Zack Snyder's Justice League* when the Amazonians warn Wonder Woman about the attack of Darkseid they light an Amazonian shrine using an arrow. There was a message engraved on the arrow. I would like to know the message that was written was in which language. What was written on the arrow i.e. the English translation of the message?

[image: Close up of the shaft of the arrow Diana is holding]

Comment: It looks like Archaic Greek to me https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaic_Greek_alphabets but that doesn't look terribly different from the far older Proto-Sinaitic script https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Sinaitic_script

Comment: I think it is Greek as the Amazons are derived from Greek Gods and when Wonder Woman goes into a cave-like structure after using the arrow to open the door the story of Darkseid and his fight with combined army is written in a similar language

Comment: "This side pointing forwards"

Comment: [Send dudes](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/send-dudes)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

During a 3/18/21 [live watch-along via scener](http://www.manofsteelanswers.com/watchwithzack/), Director Zack Snyder explained in the chat that the text on the arrow provides a means back to Themyscira:

[image]

> zacksnyder: Yes, she's going back to Themyscira. The arrow of Artemis tells her how to get there.

Comment: When is she going? It looks like she is in tunnels under the Temple of the Amazons after she retrieves the arrow there. There's no way the very next scene is her on Themyscira... she didn't see any other Amazons or stop to say hi to mom or, you know, ask her about the first time they fought the aliens?

Comment: @TylerH I think it's more a case of "she is going to go back to Themyscira eventually" rather than "she is going back right now".

The arrow serves as a warning by lighting the fire, but it also gives her the mean to go back home when she decides/needs to do so.

Comment: @user3399 Interesting conjecture; do you think the instructions were already printed on the arrow for anyone who might read it, or if they were added specifically because they knew Diana would likely be the one to retrieve the arrow?

Comment: “Take the third exit from the Bermuda Triangle, head south for about 20 miles, if you see a Dairy Queen you’ve gone too far.”

Answer (score -1):

It's written in greek and it generally makes sense. The style of painting and the language is not classical Greek, but more medieval/Byzantine writing. (You will find similar icons and language used in any greek orthodox church). It's a description of the plot. It speak of invaders from the stars, three tribes of people of the earth, parademons falling from the skies, someone rushing to a conspiracy etc etc. (haven't finished the movie yet, so I am probably missing the other references). In the last shot, the names SKOTOMIDIS and DARKSIDOS are written in greek. This is actually impressive, as it is not a simple transliteration from English, but how such names would have been written by a greek in a hellinized form.

Comment: But what does it actually say?

Comment: How can it possibly say all that in only a couple of words?